# Unable to create store with Vuex@next in TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex4

I'm currently working on Vue 3 + TypeScript project. I'd like to use Vuex for easy login management. But while I'm creating `store.ts` I'm getting this error:

```
Module '"../../vuex"' has no exported member 'createStore'.
```

My `store.ts` looks like this:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    loggedIn: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    logIn(state) {
      state.loggedIn = true;
    },
    logOut(state) {
      state.loggedIn = false;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

I've tried using Vuex@3 and Vuex@next (aka Vuex@4). Both have this error.
I've also tried clearing cache with:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

...and reinstalling all node modules. Including installing Vuex with:

```
vue add vuex
```

And to be precise I've used this too:

```
npm i --save vuex@next
```

I'm always getting same error.

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "fancy-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Default, vue-cli `main.ts`:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

Comment: Does the error really refer to store.ts ? There shouldn't be "../../vuex". It's not supposed to find a module at this path. Make sure there's no vuex.ts anywhere in the project. What is tsconfig?

Comment: There was a `vuex.d.ts` file in root dir. Deleting it solved the problem, thanks.